# Must use dispatch_semaphore_t in another thread?

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

Here is a lazy load of an array:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *dataArray;
```

```
- (NSArray *)dataArray {
    if (!_dataArray) {
        // if array is nil,load data
        dispatch_semaphore_t signal = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
        [DataManager loadListSuccess:^(NSArray * _Nonnull list) {
            self->_dataArray = list;
            dispatch_semaphore_signal(signal);
        } failure:^{
            dispatch_semaphore_signal(signal);
        }];
        dispatch_semaphore_wait(signal, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
        return _dataArray;
    } else {
        return _dataArray;
    }
}
```

What I want is when call the getter method of the `dataArray`,check whether it is nil.If nil,load data,then return.If not,return directly.

Below is the code of load data:

```
+ (void)loadListSuccess:(void (^)(NSArray *list))success failure:(dispatch_block_t)failure {
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(1 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        success(@[@"1", @"2", @"3"]);
    });
}
```

In viewDidLoad:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    NSLog(@"viewDidLoad");

    NSLog(@"self.dataArray ===== %@", self.dataArray);

    NSLog(@"load finish");
}
```

The console printed *viewDidLoad* **only**.And all the userInteractionEnabled disabled.

However,if I change the load data method to:

```
+ (void)loadListSuccess:(void (^)(NSArray *list))success failure:(dispatch_block_t)failure {
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0);
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(1 * NSEC_PER_SEC)),queue, ^{
        success(@[@"1", @"2", @"3"]);
    });
}
```

The console printed:

> 1. viewDidLoad
> 2. self.dataArray ===== (
>      1,
>      2,
>      3
>      )
> 3. load finish

Also,this is what I expected.

---

What troubled me is why in main thread it didn't work?Is there a dead lock?

Comment: Needless to say, I’d discourage the practice of using semaphores to make some potentially slow process run synchronously. And I’d definitely avoid burying that behind some accessor method. It’s best to keep the asynchronous behavior explicit (e.g. refactor to eliminate property altogether and have completion-block-based method that you’ll use instead of the property). You’ll thank yourself in the future if you simply avoid hiding inherently asynchronous behaviors behind some synchronous interface. This deadlock is just one example of the sorts of problems you’re introducing with this practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you had a deadlock on the main queue. `viewDidLoad` is called on the main queue. So you created the semaphore on the main queue.

You then wait on the semaphore on the main queue while the async call operates.

The problem is that you then attempt to call `dispatch_after` on the main queue. But the main queue is blocked waiting for the semaphore. So now you have a deadlock.

By changing the `dispatch_after` to another queue, the call to signal the semaphore can proceed and the wait ends and the main queue can continue.

When working with a semaphore, you always want to call `signal` and `wait` from two different queues to avoid a deadlock.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a dead lock

Yes, exactly. Despite your use of `dispatch_after`, which is asynchronous, your use of semaphores subverts asynchronousness and means you are effectively trying to reenter the main thread from the main thread *synchronously*. You can’t do that.